# Lint complains about missing prop coming from HOC

Tags: reactjs, lint, react-proptypes

I'm using the package [react-translate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-translate) to localise my app.

```
import React from 'react';
import { translate } from 'react-translate';


class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.t('test_string')}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default translate('Hello')(Hello);
```

In the snippet above, translate is a High Order Component, that adds the function `t` to the properties of `Hello`.

Everything works fine but lint keeps complaining because `t` is not in the propTypes.

```
error  't' is missing in props validation         react/prop-types
```

Is that normal? I guess I'm doing something wrong but I cannot tell what...

**Edit:**

As @stevejay says, I could add the t to my propTypes but I don't like this solution because - from my total ignorance in react - 1) `t` is not a property of the component itself, nor something I want to manually pass and 2) I have to add the property to all the models where I have already added the HOC and it seems redundant

Answer (score 0):

To silence the linter, you need to just add propTypes to your Hello component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { translate } from 'react-translate';

class Hello extends React.Component {
  ...
}

Hello.propTypes = {
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

Any props that a component you create uses should be declared in that way.

Comment: That means adding this property to all the components where I want to use translations. I was expecting lint to see somehow that the prop is coming from the HOC.

Comment: Specifying prop types isn't about silencing lint, it's about specifying a contract that React can use at runtime (in a development build) to check that your component has props it needs to function correctly. The prop injected by the HOC is part of that contract.